# Find size of single object in memory

Tags: julia

I know that the `varinfo()` function will give the size of all objects in memory.  This can be quite slow to execute, and will at times fail on certain objects, making the whole function hang.  Is there a way to get the size in memory of a specific object, similar to the `sys.getsizeof()` function in Python?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`varinfo()` accepts [regular expressions](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/strings/#regular-expressions) to match object names, so you can use something like

```
x = rand(100, 100)
varinfo(r"x")
```

to get info on `x`. For the size in bytes use

```
Base.summarysize(x)
```

EDIT:
Originally this answer recommended `whos()`, however as @Plankalkül mentions `whos()` has been renamed to `varinfo()`, the answer was updated accordingly.

Comment: This was renamed to `varinfo()` in Julia 1.0

Comment: Does this work for nested lists, nested dictionaries etc.? Does it work for instances of user classes?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `sizeof` function:

```rb
help?> sizeof
search: sizeof

  sizeof(s::AbstractString)

  The number of bytes in string s.

  sizeof(T)

  Size, in bytes, of the canonical binary representation of the given DataType T, if any.

julia> x = rand(100, 100);

julia> sizeof(x)
80000
```

Comment: that was unexpected, `x` is neither a string or a type.

Comment: Yes unexpected indeed if one reads only the description, you could open a PR or issue to the docs, in order to add this if you want, I can't do it right now, but will try to do so some other time, should be fairly easy to do.

Comment: Perhaps it should read `sizeof(x) \n

  Size, in bytes, of the canonical binary representation of the x object` for this method `sizeof(x) at essentials.jl:87
`

Comment: @amrods it's because not all the methods are documented separately yet: `methods(sizeof) |> length #=> 13` there are 13 methods and only 2 of them documented this way so far.

Comment: It also appears that there are a number of object types that sizeof does not work for (I had tried it previously before asking the question, but should have mentioned it in my text).  For instance, I have a sparse matrix stored as Data.  From that, I get these two different results: `Base.summarysize(Data) ## 483747752`   ;  `sizeof(Data) ## 40`

Comment: @aireties `sizeof` gives the size of an object, while `summarysize` sums the size of an object as well as its fields recursively. `Data` contains some references to its fields which are not bit types, so `sizeof` only counts the pointer sizes, rather than the actually data size.